# emma maven plugin code highlighting

Tags: maven-2, emma

is it possible to have the output html reports have highlighting where code was covered in a maven build? I know you can in standalone emma and with ant, but I haven't yet figured out how to do this with maven and emma. Thanks.

Jeff

Comment: Which maven version? 1.x, 2.x? Which emma-maven plugin?

Comment: I am using 1.0 alpha (from org.codehaus.mojo).

Comment: maven version 2.1 (the 1.0 alpha is the emma maven plugin version)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible with the Emma Maven plugin, but this is the default behaviour for the [Cobertura Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/). It also gives you the number of times a line is hit, which can be useful in determining where your testing is minimal. See this [report](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/sample-maven-shared-io-report/index.html) for an example of the output.

I find Cobertura and Emma to be largely interchangeable in terms of coverage checking, just that Cobertura has a better Maven plugin and Emma has a better Eclipse plugin in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour of the EMMA plugin if you run `mvn emma:emma` or add it to the `<reporting>` element. You can find a working example here: http://github.com/brettporter/centrepoint/blob/master/centrepoint/modules/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `sourcepath=` attribute on the `report` tag and you to specify at least(?) coverage `depth="method"` on the html tag if I remember correctly.

Comment: I tried that and ran the emma plugin on debug and it was using the correct sourcepath, but still no luck. I figured it had to be on line coverage for line highlighting, but the maven plugin didn't have that option.